# how to get users' posts based on their levels in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

Laravel 8.4
MySQL
PHP 7.4

I have a Rank model with a ranks table that is related to my User model through the *hasmany* relationship and User model *belongsto* the Rank model

Also there is User model that is related to the Post model through the same relationship as above.

I want to get all the posts but is ordered by the ranks of the users who posted it.

so how will I go about writing such query?

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to StackOverflow! Thank you for your question, we always like to help. However, I think that we need a little more information in order to answer it. Maybe you can include some code samples of what you've done already? We always encourage people to create well-researched questions.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but this SQL query is probably what you're looking for:

```sql
SELECT posts.*, ranks.name AS rank_name, users.id AS user_id FROM posts
  JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id -- Join the users table with the posts table
  JOIN ranks ON users.rank_id = ranks.id -- Join the ranks table with the users table
  ORDER BY rank_name;
```

This query would return each post, along with a "column" called `rank_name` containing the rank, and `user_id` which would contain the user's id. The `ORDER BY` would return the results ordered by the rank name, essentially grouping them together by rank (e.g. all posts written by a user with "Rank 1" would be put together). You can run it as-is with `DB::select`, or here's my approximation with the query builder:

```php
$posts = DB::table('posts')
         ->select('posts.*', 'ranks.name AS rank_name', 'users.id AS user_id')
         ->join('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
         ->join('ranks', 'users.rank_id', '=', 'ranks.id')
         ->orderBy('rank_name');
```

It's also worth pointing out that you don't technically need to use `ranks.name AS rank_name` (the same goes for `users.id AS user_id`); you could just order directly by `ranks.name`. However, I find the former much easier to work with in Laravel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the code I've actually been searching for